# Android screen resolutions and density. Packages of images

Tags: android, screen-size

I have a problem in my android app:
I have 4 packages of images (for 320x240, 800x480, 854x480 and 1024x600 resolutions).

I want to have one layout which should look good for any resolution or density (of my 4 packages). Now if I set Padding Left 120 dip for example I have different offsets if different density. How to make offsets identical in appearance for any density?
In which folder should I put my pictures so that my layout look good for any density screen? Also what should I write in manifest file for correct work of the app for any density?

Please help!!!
Thanks and sorry for my English...

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html read this guide on supporting multiple screens

Answer (score 0):

there are various possibilities to dynamically be ready to every screen size.

what you should do, is add the different `drawable` directories. there are many different accepted directories that will dynamically use the correct images in the users device.

try reading the [adroids supporting different screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article.

good luck